# The bar moves to the left and right

Tags: java, android-studio

I would like to create a sliding bar to the left and to the right, which will contain dates. Could someone give me some tips on how I could achieve something like that? Because I have no idea how to go about it.

[image]

Comment: Show some of the code you are using

Comment: I can't show the code, because as I wrote above, I have no idea how to get to this endeavor to achieve the desired result. That's why I emphasized that I would ask for some valuable tips that would help me solve this problem.

Comment: Look into the Graphics API documents. You can draw lines with that object and display them to an image or frame, and also much more. Graphics#fillRect(x, y, width, height); I believe

Comment: You gave me a function that draws equal rectangles, right? And I meant something completely different. I mean the situation in which I have such a strap as above, but it is a sliding strap. And how can I do so that after moving my finger to the right or to the left, the dates change +1 day or -1 day depending on which direction I have moved. This is to remind "carousels" in inverted commas.